# Custom prefix for components Angular and WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I initially started a few months ago a project in Angular using Visual Studio Code editor.

Today I made the switch to WebStorm and I also upgraded my project to Angular 4.0.

While my project is running nice without any errors, I receive the following error in WebStorm:

> TSLint: The selector of the component "ConnectionStatusComponent"
>   should have prefix "app" (
>   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#02-07) (component-selector)

Following that link I realized that is a good practice to add a custom prefix to component selector to `prevent name collisions with components in other apps and with native HTML elements`

I understand that. My question is why am I forced to use the `app` prefix and not other prefix? If I put other prefix then `app`, WebStorm will mark the line as error.

According to the style guide from that link:

> Do use a custom prefix for a component selector. For example, the
>   prefix toh represents from Tour of Heroes and the prefix admin
>   represents an admin feature area.

I can use whatever prefix I want. Is there a rule on the prefix name?

Comment: You can change this settings in tslint file under the setting of "component-selector" - remove the "app" from the array

Comment: I use multiple prefixes per component. First is app to differentiate my components. Seconds is name of feature module. Third is parent view. ie. `app-core-login-footer`. I guess, as time goes on that I will hit the fourth level.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no strict rules on prefix name.   If you are using the CLI, you can edit the `prefix` node under `apps` in the `angular-cli.json`.   This will make the cli create new components with whatever prefix you decide.  For `tslint.json` you can set both component and directive rules:

```
"directive-selector": [true, "attribute", "app", "camelCase"],
"component-selector": [true, "element", "app", "kebab-case"],
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

If you want to use more than one prefix, you can specify them in an array like this([example from here](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer#recommended-configuration)):

```
//RULES: [ENABLED, "attribute" | "element", "selectorPrefix" | ["listOfPrefixes"], "camelCase" | "kebab-case"]
  "directive-selector": [true, "attribute", ["dir-prefix1", "dir-prefix2"], "camelCase"],
  "component-selector": [true, "element", ["cmp-prefix1", "cmp-prefix2"], "kebab-case"],
```

- In the array, the first argument is a boolean for whether it is
  enabled or not.
- The second argument is a union type with choices `attribute` or
  `element`.
- The third argument is either a string for a single prefix or an array
  for a list of prefixes.
- And the fourth argument is a union type of either `kebab-case` or
  `camelCase`.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. What if I want to use multiple prefixes like "admin", "user" , etc.. ? Is there a way to do that in tslint.json?

Comment: Thanks, i was having the same issue in Webstorm

Comment: the tslint in the src folder not the root =)